# VertexAI doesn't detect any rows in my uploaded datasets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I tried creating a dataset in VertexAI (no coding, just clicking on the dashboard). No matter if I choose to upload it from the computer or to import it from the bucket in Google Storage, the dataset appears empty.

Only the columns are detected, but no other data. The extension is csv. Obviously, the csv does have data when I open it in Excel or so. Switching regions doesn't do anything either.

Why is that? I worked with AutoML in the past and I had zero issues.

Comment: Is it possible to share the CSV file which you are trying to import?

Comment: @kiranmathew it's just something taken from Kaggle or GitHub (I tried with several), like: https://gist.github.com/netj/8836201#file-iris-csv or https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/lodetomasi1995/income-classification

Comment: Can use the ` GENERATING STATISTICS` button to see if it displays the rows. Which type of model you are using is it `Regression/classification` or `Forecasting`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Google Spreadsheet instead of Excel.
Create new Google Spreadsheet and paste the data into the file.
And perform export as CSV.

Comment: How would that help? Please read [answer].